# Random sound from array Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I am trying to play a random sound effect once the button is click. Basically, I created an array of sound as shown below. My goal is, when the users click the button, I want to pick a random sound from an array, this only works once the page is refreshed. But when the users click the button at the second or third time, it will return just return the same result over and over again.

```
function sound_return(){
    var sound_array = ["sound1.mp3", "sound2.mp3"];
    var sound = sound_array[Math.floor(Math.random() * sound_array.length)];
        return sound;
    }

        var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
        audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'sound/'+sound_return());
        audioElement.load()
        $.get();
        audioElement.addEventListener("load", function() {
        audioElement.play();
        }, true);

    $('#sound').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            audioElement.play();    
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the audio source and load it during every click

```
function sound_return(){
    var sound_array = ["sound1.mp3", "sound2.mp3"];
    var sound = sound_array[Math.floor(Math.random() * sound_array.length)];
    return sound;
}

var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
audioElement.addEventListener("load", function() {
    audioElement.play();
    btn.hide();
}, true);
audioElement.addEventListener("ended", function() {
    btn.show();
}, true);


var btn = $('#sound').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'sound/'+sound_return());
    audioElement.load();
});
```

Comment: My fault, it is working. However, I am getting different issue. Unlike before, the user is now allow to play the audio from the beginning by clicking the button over and over even when the audio is not finish yet.

Comment: in that case you need to disable the button when the audio start playing and enable it once it ends

Comment: But how can I detect once the audio is still playing or when it is finished?